# Sending file in API request .NET

Tags: c#, .net

I have an enpoint that I send request via Postman form-data. Request has 2 keys.

```
message : string
file: File
```

this works ok. So, I want to send the same request in C# code. In c# I just need to choose file from local, somehow convert it to proper format, assign it to `file` property in request Model, I mean I can not change the logic how request is sent. I must not write additional logic to HttpRequest or MultipartFormDataContent etc (I can not even see this part how it is sent).  Just need to add Model to this request body.
I have model RequestModel

```
public class RequestModel
{
[JsonProperty("message")]
public string Message {get; set; }

[JsonProperty("file")]
public whateverType File {get; set; }
}
```

message part works, so I need to assign local file to File property. how can I do that. I tried almost everything but it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: .Net Core or .net Framwork?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload files in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35379309/how-to-upload-files-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: This SO thread is similar for asp.net core: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54411250/how-to-send-multipart-form-data-to-asp-net-core-web-api

Comment: in .net 6. these answers do not solve my problem. simply I need to convert the way postman converts. when i choose file in postman how it converts this file? what is the equivalent of converted type in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to keep the file in your model.

this is an example to post a model just by knowing the file name.

```cs
var model = new RequestModel();

// ... fill the model with some data
model.Message = "test";
model.File = @"c:\test.jpg";

using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
{
    var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
    form.Add(new StringContent(model.Message), nameof(RequestModel.Message));

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(model.File);
    form.Add(new ByteArrayContent(bytes, 0, bytes.Length), "profile_pic", "hello1.jpg");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("PostUrl", form);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    var sd = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result; // you should use await if your method is async ...
}

public class RequestModel
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public string File { get; set; } // simply use file-path
}
```

Comment: I choose file from local directory (I do not need [FromForm]) and the main part is the body of this method.

Comment: i have tried this: error:Could not create an instance of type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IFormFile.

Comment: ContentType = '((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile)model.attachment).ContentType' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: You should create an instance of `FormFile` not `IFormFile`

Comment: yep, i'm creating an instance of FormFile

Comment: You can set the content type manually. I've updated the answer

Comment: still getting "NullReferenceException" for IFormFile

Comment: This is how you can create the request model with a file manually. obviously, here `model.File` is not null. try to debug your code and find the null value, or ask another question on StackOverflow about it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63889929/why-do-i-get-an-could-not-create-an-instance-of-type-microsoft-aspnetcore-http - looking to this problem, but i think this is not my case

Comment: I think your new problem is related to sending this model to the API. You have to use `FormUrlEncodedContent` for this.

Comment: Now I realized your question was misleading! You don't need to include the file in the request model, You should've asked how to make a post request with a file. this is different since here you can not use JSON serializer for this end-point

Comment: I can not reach Request this is the problem, I just need to create request model

Comment: when I send the same request with Postman it works, I send request from form-data, and send "message":string and "attachment": file

Comment: so, in c# i can assign message property, now need to assign file property. file property is required, without it message works

Comment: maybe the property should not be IFormFile

Comment: No, it's not that simple, You should update the question and add your CreateRequest method, your problem is related to that method, not the model. I'm 99 percent sure you are trying to use JSON serializers that is not possible for this specific end-point

Comment: Simply you can not post a JSON with a file together.

Comment: You must do something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19983672/786376 This is what postman is doing to post your request.

Comment: yes, thanks. i can not change method to yours as you have mentioned, but i think i can add multipart/form-data to support this request